# jquery tabs and conditional ruby code on document.ready()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I want to load my jquery tabs if a certain condition is true. Is it possible to have a ruby if statement embedded in  document.ready() or by the time that is processed its too late? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    <% if @event.scheduled.empty? %>
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();    
    <% end %>   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does the file that is in have .erb as an extension?

Comment: Yes it is in a show.html.erb file

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me using rails 3.1. Are you sure `@event.scheduled.empty?` is the right condition to use?

Answer (score 2):

As you are using ruby if condition in JQuery, you need to come out of that, you can make that from using escape_javascript tag. try this,

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <%= escape_javascript(if @event.scheduled.empty?) %>
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();    
    <% end %>   
  });    
</script>
```